# .htaccess to use REQUEST_URI returns 500 error code. How to fix it? Apache2 + PHP

Tags: php, apache2, friendly-url

Good morning.

Linux Ubuntu 20.04, with Apache2 and PHP 7.4. I'm using friendly URL in PHP app by $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

**Code**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I was have using this code in the same development server, but on Mint Linux 18.x. I needed format and choused O.S.

On Apache2 I have:

```
<Directory /home/tecnico/Site_Projects/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Virtual host 000-default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/tecnico/Site_Projects
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Enable .htaccess and added only now, after 500 error
    <Directory /home/tecnico/Site_Projects/bignew>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # Server
    ServerAdmin webmaster@bigpecasnew.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/home/tecnico/Site_Projects/bignew/"
    ServerName bigpecasnew.localhost
    ServerAlias www.bigpecasnew.localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bigpecasnew.localhost.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bigpecasnew.localhost.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What is wrong? It was functionaly in Mint Linux.

[image]

Error log:

```
[Wed Sep 23 11:15:12.994037 2020] [core:alert] [pid 5277] [client ::1:41838] /home/tecnico/Site_Projects/bignew/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not >
```

Error log v-host specifc appliction:

```
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:08:23:09 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:08:23:16 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:08:30:06 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:08:30:10 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:09:52 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:09:53 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:13:30 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:13:30 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:37:25 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:37:26 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:37:30 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:37:30 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:43:05 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:09:43:06 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:11:15:24 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [23/Sep/2020:11:15:24 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://bigpecasnew.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safa>
```

Comment: What is the full error message in the error log? Where's the code that throws the error? Have you done a `var_dump($_SERVER);` to see what it actually contains?

Comment: _“What is wrong?”_ - you showing up here, without having checked what the error log has to say about this first of all.

Comment: Mr. @04FS, I edit the post including log and print. Thanks for critics.

Comment: Mr. @Magnus Eriksson, I edit the post including log and print. Thanks for critics.

Comment: _"Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'"_ - Have you installed and enabled mod_rewrite for Apache?

Comment: Thank you, Mr. @Magnus Eriksson. It's solved. The Answer is below.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Good afternoon, folks!

I was read in another post here, in stackoverflow, and I understand errorly that I should write the command  *a2enmod rewrite* inside apache2.conf archive - yes! You understand my error - and after that I exclude this code, because returne error.

Reading another posts, I found one clearly explaining be necessary, after set configurations - all that I had already implemented - implements command: ***sudo a2enmod rewrite*** and ***sudo systemctl restart apache2***. After... application it's run normally.

I don't remenber had be necessary run this command in Mint Linux after set configuration. I remember only be necessary run sudo *systemctl restart apache2*.

Sorry if question was bad.